# PHP: From ajax Items are not deleting when click on all delete checkbox

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to delete all items when I check then select all checkbox, but it is deleting the single item.

Here is the code where I am getting all items id's on click on checkbox

```
    $delete_vehicle_trim =Item::find($request->deletetrimid);

        if ($delete_vehicle_trim != null) {
            $delete_vehicle_trim->delete();
            return response()->json(['msg'=>'Record Delete Successfully']);
        }

        else {
            return response()->json(['msg'=>'Error In Delete']);
        }
```

on ajax call `trim = []` I am getting multiples id in this array

```
function viewtrim(id){

    $('#select-all').click(function(event) {   
         var trim = [];
            $.each($("input[name='checkbox']:checked"), function(){            
                trim.push($(this).val());
              
            });
            alert("Id is: " + trim.join(", "));
      
        $('#select-all').on('click', function(e) {
            var allVals = [];  
            $("checkbox:checked").each(function() {  
                id.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
            });  
        });
       
        $.ajax({
            url : 'viewtrim/' +viewtrimid,
            type : 'GET',
            data : {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                'viewtrimid': viewtrimid,
                "_method": 'GET',
            },
            
            }
        });
     
    }

    console.log($("input[name=checkbox]").val());
```

Any help?

Comment: Why are you adding another click handler to the same element, inside the click handler you already have on it? That does not make much sense. (Plus, if you are selecting the checkboxes with `:checked`, how is that even "all" of them?) And you probably need a different method on the server side, than `Item::find` (I doubt that can handle a comma-separated list of IDs as parameter?), and then _loop over_ the found items to delete them

Comment: Show your controller.

Comment: There are some problems in the JS: 1) one event handler added inside another, both doing the same-ish thing?  One should be removed.  2) When the AJAX fires it tries to use `viewtrimid`, which has not been set.  Separately, just guessing but should `name='checkbox'` actually be `type='checkbox'`?  Also, you don't need to specify `_method` for GET or POST, remove that.  Lastly, you should delete things using a POST, not GET (and that makes use of your CSRF, which is not used in a GET).